# Unable to set callerID using ARI

Tags: asterisk

I have a java stasis application on Asterisk 14 using ari4java. It mostly works great. I am now trying to receive an external call and relay it back out. I do following

1. Incoming call enters Stasis
2. Create bridge
3. Add first call(channel) to bridge
4. Create channel
5. Add second channel to bridge
6. Dial( secondChID, "Local/2601", 30)

No matter what I try, the second outbound call gets the callerID of the first inbound call. That is actually OK for many calls, but in this case I want to set another callerId.

Before Dial() I have tried to setChannelVar(CALLERID(num)) and this value I can see in all events coming from Asterisk. But once the SIP call is placed, no sign of my callerID.

I doubt it is the ari4java doing anything wrong as I see the callerID in all the "dial" events. I thought I could force a callerID in sip.conf, but unable to do that too.

Comment: Please add logs from asterisk console

Comment: A log file can be found here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6OtrM5F9wLseVZ4WkdPeUgwZjQ

Comment: If have run these commands before the Dial() command
   ari.channels().setChannelVar( secondChId, "SIPFROMUSER", "22113344" );
   ari.channels().setChannelVar( secondChId, "SIPFROMDOMAIN", "Teletopia.no" );
   ari.channels().setChannelVar( secondChId, "CALLERID(num)", "22113366" );
   ari.channels().setChannelVar( secondChId, "CALLERID(name)", "Teletopia TeleTorg1" );

Both numbers can be seen in the attached log, but not in the SIP messages.

Comment: So what caller-id you want to show and what actual caller-id you see?

Comment: I expect to see either SIPFROMUSER or CALLERID(num) which I set, not sure which one is relevant in this case, But instead I see the callerId of the first incoming call. I have read somewhere that Asterisk copies callId info from one call to the other (for transfer/forwarding scenarios), but I can not understand why I cannot override that.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

To show the correct caller id on the outbound call you need to set the `connectedline` variable before `Dial()`.

`setChannelVar(CONNECTEDLINE(all,i)=name <number>)`